# How to execute custom code after reports are generated

Tags: playwright, jira-xray

I am currently trying to setup some integration of my Playwright tests with Xray Cloud. I am using [playwright-junit-reporter](https://github.com/Xray-App/playwright-junit-reporter) to generate JUnit reports with additional info required by Xray API and [xray-automation-js](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-automation-js) to upload the JUnit.xml results to the Xray Cloud.

I need to call the `xrayClient.submitResults(reportFile, reportConfig)` method after the reports are being generated by Playwright framework.

I have tried to make the call in a `globalTeardown` file that I then call in `playwright.config.ts` file (as described [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#example)), but the call to gliobalTeardown seems to be done before generating the reports.

The question is: where in my Playwright project I can execute code after the tests are finished and reports generated, so that I can upload the results to Xray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the way to handle report uploads. As you rightly alluded to, playwright reports are exactly that, a report on the run. And the run is the start to finish cycle through the test/s. As such, uploading a report couldn't and shouldn't be done within the test code.

This is best handled in my opinion, in your CI/CD pipeline. I cant give code examples here as this is entirely dependant on your services, if you use Docker, Infrastructure etc. But, you should add a step in your pipeline to do the upload to XRay.

How that looks is again subjective, and I am happy to help in the comments or DM, but you should not scope this to your test project, and instead push this to your CI.

Comment: I was going to answer but I agree with this answer; I would leave the upload process as a step outside of the logic of running the tests. You can even create a npm task in the project, if you want, to implement just the upload and then call it from the CI/CD pipeline

Comment: Yes indeed it makes sense, thanks for sharing. I would work on improving the custom JSON report based on our needs and write a separate project to be called by the Jenkins pipeline after the test execution